# MatLab error: Too many input arguments

Tags: matlab, function, input, parameters, arguments

I have defined a function like this:

```
function [phi_D,phi_S,v_S] =libem2(n_D,p_D,n_S,vertpts_S,elemvert_S,alpha_S,beta_S,f_S)
```

Clearly `libem2` takes in 8 arguments. This function is actually a helper function for another function named `interiorsquaretest`. So when I try to call `libem2` in `interiorsquaretest` like this:

```
[phi_D, phi_S,v_S] =libem2(5,points,32,vertpts,elemvert,a,b,F);
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Error using libem2
Too many input arguments.

Error in interiorsquaretest (line 73)
      [phi_D, phi_S,v_S] =libem2(5,points,32,vertpts,elemvert,a,b,F);
```

How is this possible! I am passing 8 arguments and `libem2` expects 8 arguments! Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably another `libem2` function defined somewhere - either in another file, or in the *same* file that defines `interiorsquaretest`.

First, try running

```
which libem2
```

at the MATLAB prompt, from the same directory that `interiorsquaretest.m` lives in, and see if it gives the file that you expect.  If it reveals another file, problem solved.

If not, look to see if another `libem2` is defined in your `interiorsquaretest.m` file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another file, with the same name and different number of arguments, somewhere in your Path settings.